Reversing a queue with only one extra varable
I had a test for college recently and got a task I believe is imposible.
Write a function

void QuReverse(Queue *Q)

which will reverse the order of the given queue using only one extra variable of the type that is written in the queue and one extra int variable.
This is everything that was given in the whole task. I know how to do it if I know the length of the queue, but we were not given the length and I think we can't calculate it because there is no rule that elements are unique.
We could use standard queue functions QuEnqueue, QuDequeue, QuMakeNull, QuEmpty, QuFront. And we could make more functions but with the same variable restrictions.
I would appreciate very much if someone can help.
I had no idea how to do it with these restrictions so I did it with a Stack which was worth half the points.

You probably know that you can reverse a queue using a stack. But you can't create an explicit stack. Maybe you could do it with recursion?

Oh wow thank you I don't know how I didn't think of that.
